# eBay Feed API uploadFile call return 2003 error - PHP Curl

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-lms

I want to achieve the following goal. Migrating my File Exchange Application to new eBay feed api.

Please check the concern page.

**API - Feed Reference:**

[Link to File Exchange Migration Procedure](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/static/file-exchange-migration/fx-to-feed-steps-required-for-migration.html)

[Link to eBay Sell Feed API](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/feed/resources/task/methods/uploadFile#request.fileName)

I am adopting their procedure as stated on the above links but I am receiving the following error while calling Sell Feed API -> uploadFile method.

```
"errorId": 2003,
      "domain": "ACCESS",
      "category": "APPLICATION",
      "message": "Internal error",
      "longMessage": "There was a problem with an eBay internal system or process. Contact eBay developer support for assistance",
      "parameters": [
        { "name": "code",  "value": "400"  },
        { "name": "message", "value": "HTTP 400 Bad Request"  }
```

**Please check my request.**

Endpoint: "https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/task-40-xxxxxxxxx/upload_file"

**Request Headers:**

```
Authorization:Bearer myToken
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:multipart/form-data
X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID: EBAY_US
```

**Payload:**

```
{ 
"fileName" : "https://virtualwebdesk.com/brad/feed.csv",
"name" : "file",
"type" : "form-data"
}
```

***Please Note: I create TaskID first and then pass in the call.***

Comment: did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

```
    This code is in C# - RestClient
    
    createTask
    ==========
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer v^1.1#i^1****** YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN *********Ql3QYER3BQAAA==");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID", "EBAY_GB");
    var body = @"{
    " + "\n" +
    @"  ""schemaVersion"": ""1149"",
    " + "\n" +
    @"  ""feedType"": ""LMS_REVISE_INVENTORY_STATUS""
    " + "\n" +
    @"}";
    request.AddParameter("application/json", body,  ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    
    Response:
    location:https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/task-12-1127376027
    
    task-12-1127376027 is your TaskID
    
    uploadFile
    ==========
test.xml
--------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<BulkDataExchangeRequests xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Header>
        <Version>685</Version>
        <SiteID>3</SiteID>
    </Header>
    <ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
        <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
        <MessageID>test-1111</MessageID>
        <Version>637</Version>
        <InventoryStatus ComplexType="InventoryStatusType">
            <SKU>test-1111</SKU>
            <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        </InventoryStatus>
    </ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>
    <ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
        <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
        <MessageID>test-2222</MessageID>
        <Version>637</Version>
        <InventoryStatus ComplexType="InventoryStatusType">
            <SKU>test-2222</SKU>
            <Quantity>0</Quantity>
        </InventoryStatus>
    </ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>
</BulkDataExchangeRequests>


    var client = new RestClient("https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/task-12-1127376027/upload_file");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer v^1.1#i^1****** YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN *********Ql3QYER3BQAAA==");
    request.AddHeader("X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID", "EBAY_GB");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    request.AddParameter("fileName", "test.xml");
    request.AddFile("file", "F:/test.xml");
    request.AddParameter("type", "form-data");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    
    Response: "StatusCode: OK, Content-Type: , Content-Length: 0)"
    
    getTask
    ========
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/task-12-1235290549");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer v^1.1#i^1****** YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN *********Ql3QYER3BQAAA==");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    
    Response:
    {
        "taskId": "task-12-1127376027",
        "status": "COMPLETED",
        "feedType": "LMS_REVISE_INVENTORY_STATUS",
        "creationDate": "2022-02-09T11:39:50.000Z",
        "completionDate": "2022-02-09T11:50:34.000Z",
        "uploadSummary": {
            "successCount": 2,
            "failureCount": 0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it,

```
 <InventoryStatus ComplexType="InventoryStatusType"> => <InventoryStatus>
```

```html
    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<BulkDataExchangeRequests xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Header>
        <Version>685</Version>
        <SiteID>0</SiteID>
    </Header>
    <ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <InventoryStatus>
            <ItemID>2645246754</ItemID>
            <Quantity>2</Quantity>
            <SKU>SY0195Y</SKU>
        </InventoryStatus>
        <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
        <MessageID>ttt33</MessageID>
        <Version>637</Version>
        <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
    </ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>
</BulkDataExchangeRequests>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/s0y3dk/uploading_a_csv_using_ebay_feed_api_endpoints/

Find solution here, need to remove "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" in the header, and add files to the request.

Here is the example code of python.

```
def uploadFile(token, task_id, file_name, file_path):
    url = "https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/"+task_id+"/upload_file"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID": "EBAY_AU"
    }

    form_data = {
      "name": "file",
      "fileName": file_name,
      "type": "form-data"
    }

    files = {
        "file": (file_name, open(file_path, "rb"))
    }
    response = requests.post(url,headers=headers, data=form_data, files=files)
    return response

uploadFile("myToken", "my_task_id", "my_file_name.csv", "C:/my_file_path")
```